# libvlcsharp - how to force multicast from rtsp stream camera

Tags: .net, multicast, libvlcsharp

I am developing an app in .net using libvlcsharp VideoView control.
I need to pull multicast streams from cameras and so I want to set the command line parameter --rtsp-mcast.

The purpose of the app is to stress test a video system using a large number of camera streams but I have a limited number of cameras so I need multiple streams coming from a few cameras.

e.g. what it would look like using vlc

```
vlc --rtsp-mcast rtsp://<ip>/axis-media/media.amp
```

How I test. I run the above once and note the network traffic in task manager and Resouce monitor then I run the same command again and see that the network traffic didn't increase. Also I use:

```
netstat -aon
```

I look up the PID of each instance of vlc and find that both are using the same two UDP ports to send and receive data.

However when I use the following code to initialize LibVLC

```
singleLibVLC = new LibVLC(" --rtsp-mcast " );
```

and run with two streams from the same camera the network traffic doubles and that there are two different ephemeral TCP ports open for the PID assigned to my test application.

I understand the "--rtsp-mcast" directive is ultimately forwarded to the live555 module. Is this the problem? It's not possible to get there from here. Or... is there a different way to pass this parameter?

Also is there something that needs to be done in the application to allow for the UDP transport to work. It seems that either VLC or the axis camera defaults to TCP if it can't find a way to use the UDP connection.

@mfkl,
Removed leading spaces for command line options as in

```
singleLibVLC = new LibVLC("--verbose=2 --rtsp-mcast");
```

This gets me using UPD for both copies of stream but each stream is using a different pair of ports.

I modified my command line test as follows:

```
vlc --verbose=2 --file-logging --logfile="%appdata%\vlc\out.log" --rtsp-mcast rtsp://etc.
```

Comparing to vlc log in visual studio output window.

Comment: @mfkl - generated logs from vlc command line and from vlcsharp in visual studio. These logs have similar log messages but are very different and hard to compare on a line by line basis. To start with I isolated the "using ... module" statements and found that the vlc log had over 1000 using statements and the VLCSharp log had 76. I visually examined the first 50 lines in both and found one item in the VLC log that I didn't find in the VLCSharp log: "cache_read debug: Using stream method for AStream*". There are other items as well but they didn't seem to be related to stream management like

Comment: continuation... using playlist export module "export". Is the lack of the Using stream_filter module "cache_read" (also missing) an issue for using multicast packets transported over UDP. If so how do I force VLCSharp to load and use this module?

Comment: @mfkl So the VLC log (which streams multicast) has  "cache_read debug: Using stream method for AStream*" the VLC log has no reference to GStreamer whereas the vlcsharp log has several lines like this: Server: GStreamer RTSP server. The vlcsharp log has no reference to AStream*. I need some help understanding the difference and how to ask the VLCSharp library to use the AStream* if this indeed is what I need to do.

Comment: @mfkl - gave up on trying to get the Axis camera to switch over to multicast using the "--rtsp-mcast" instead used vlc to transcode from the rtsp unicast stream to an RTP/multicast stream and then ingested that into the VLCSharp library in my .net app.. This solved my immediate problem of developing a test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> singleLibVLC = new LibVLC(" --rtsp-mcast " );

Remove the spaces at the beginning and end of your string.

Share the full logs, add "--verbose=2" to LibVLC ctor.

> Or... is there a different way to pass this parameter?

`media.AddOption(":rtsp-mcast")` though I doubt it'd work any better.

> Also is there something that needs to be done in the application to allow for the UDP transport to work

Using `udp://blabla` as a media MRL would be a way.

Compare verbose logging of VLC (where it works) with your libvlc based app (where it doesn't work), this is a good way to troubleshoot what steps might be missing from your app, that the VLC app does automagically.

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: I was unable to solve this problem directly - that is, I can't get the control to behave like VLC when streaming the Axis camera. So I used another computer to ingest the Axis stream and produce a UDP stream and was able to do my stress test with one camera and 16 instances of the control in one application. So I will mark this as a solution.